# RSS feed of products for exporting

Tags: xml, rss

Currently I'm stuck with a plain XML/RSS feed, I want to be able to use more "attributes" as fields in my RSS, how can this be done? My fields inside Items are now named title, link, sku, price and category. This is not accepted by the rss w3 validator. But I don't think that I understand the concept of namespaces, and if they are needed or I can do my feed this way?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Products from Category 1</title>
<link>www.linktoshop.com</link>
<description>Links from a category on my shop</description>
{{block type="product"}}
<item>
    <title>{{var title}}</title>
    <link>{{var link}}</link>
    <sku>{{var sku}}</sku>
    <price>{{var price}}</price>
    <category>{{var category}}</category>
</item>
{{/block}}
</channel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSS elements are not bound to a namespace. Any elements in an RSS feed that are not bound to a namespace must be the RSS elements. You can add custom elements to your RSS feed items, but they need to be in a namespace. For example:

```
<p:sku xmlns:p="urn:rfidic:product:core:ACME:sku">{{var sku}}</p:sku>
<g:price xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">{{var price}}</g:price>
```

[Namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) help uniquely qualify elements and attributes.

However, unless you use a [well-known vocabulary](http://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/howto/declare_namespaces.html), the validator will likely still report warnings that the namespace is unknown and your data may not be very inter-operable with other systems. You might want to check some of those XML vocabularies to see if any of your content would fit.

---

Alternatively, you could also just use the [`<category>` element with a domain attribute](http://www.rssboard.org/rss-profile#element-channel-item-category):

```
<category domain="sku">{{var sku}}</category>
<category domain="price">{{var price}}</category>
```